# converting jquery object to regular js within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

if a jquery object is passed into a function, can I get the 'regular' js out of it so I can run things like:

```
foo($(this))

function foo(node){
    var jsnode = regular js object
    var num = (jsnode.id).substr((jsnode.id).length-1, 1);
}
```

If it's quite complicated I can just work with the jQuery... just curious!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method:

```
var jsnode = node.get(0); //Returns the node at index 0
```

Or you can use the array notation:

```
var jsnode = node[0]; //Also returns the node at index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just access the regular JavaScript at `node[0]`